# AttributeError: type object 'User' has no attribute 'USERNAME_FIELD'

Tags: python, django, model, attributes

This is my code. I understand that the User class needs USERNAME_FIELD, but I have that, so I am not sure exactly what the issue is. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
# User model
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    # email
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    # active status
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    # admin status
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    # first name
    fname = models.TextField(default="")
    # last name
    lname = models.TextField(default="")
    # what year of graduation
    year = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
```

Comment: Please share *code*, no *images* of code.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thank you.

Comment: Where is the code that when you execute is throwing this error? In general, i'd recommend you put the variables inside a `def __init__(self):` (constructor method) and put `self.` before every variable

Answer (score 0):

Add a username=None field in the User model.